# how to clear the radio buttons using check box un check

Tags: javascript

I was trying to clear the radio buttons using check box uncheck. I'm able to get the sample for it. But you have same set is there more than once in my form. I want to have generic method that can be used across the sets.

Can some help me. Here is my code. I want to use java script for this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

function loopForm(form) {
    var cbResults = 'Checkboxes: ';
    var radioResults = 'Radio buttons: ';
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {
        if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            if (form.elements[i].checked == true) {
                cbResults += form.elements[i].value + ' ';
            }
        }
        if (form.elements[i].type == 'radio') {
            if (form.elements[i].checked == true) {
                radioResults += form.elements[i].value + ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("cbResults").innerHTML = cbResults;
    document.getElementById("radioResults").innerHTML = radioResults;
}

function loopForm123(form) {

    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {

        if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            if (form.elements[i].checked == true) {
                alert('insde for loop1');
                form.elements[i].checked == false;
                alert('insde for loop3');
            }
        }
        if (form.elements[i].type == 'radio') {
            if (form.elements[i].checked == true) {
                alert('insde for loop2');
                form.elements[i].checked == false;
                alert('insde for loop4');
            }
        }
    }

}

</script>
<body>
<form name="thisForm">
I like to program in:<p>
<input type="checkbox" value="PHP" >PHP<p>
<input type="checkbox" value="Perl">Perl<p>
<input type="checkbox" value="Ruby">Ruby<p>
<input type="checkbox" value="ASP">ASP<p>
<hr>
I like to eat:<p>
<input type="radio" value="Snickers" name="candy" >Snickers<p>
<input type="radio" value="Hershey's" name="candy">Hershey's<p>
<input type="radio" value="M&M's" name="candy">M&M's<p>
<input type="radio" value="Nerds" name="candy">Nerds<p>
<hr>
I like to drink:<p>
<input type="radio" value="Coke" name="drink" >Coke<p>
<input type="radio" value="Gatorade" name="drink">Gatorade<p>
<input type="radio" value="Pepsi" name="drink">Pepsi<p>
<input type="radio" value="Milk" name="drink">Milk<p>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Submit" onclick="loopForm123(document.thisForm);"> 
</form>
<p>
<div id="cbResults"></div>
<div id="radioResults"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zzrVN/

Comment: Have you written any JavaScript yourself? Then maybe we can tell you where you are going wrong.

Comment: I have tired this example [link]http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?100221-Clear-radio-button-values-when-checkbox-unchecked"[link] here they have checked with type radio.

Comment: Put into a JSFiddle for anyone wanting to help: http://jsfiddle.net/zzrVN/

Comment: can u set up a fiddle?

Comment: Can you use jQuery for this, or does it need to be plain JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you Mark jsfiddle.i am trying with java script. since i have not used jquery. if it is easy in doing that i will add import them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use a reset button to clear the form?

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset Form" />
```

But to answer your question, if you are able to use jQuery then you can do this very easily:

jQuery method: http://jsfiddle.net/zzrVN/2/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#clearCheckboxes').click( function() {
        $('[name="thisForm"] input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $('[name="thisForm"] input:radio').removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

To use jQuery you just need to add one script tag to your document:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However if you do not want to use jQuery then the pure JavaScript solution would be something like:

```
var inputItems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0;i<inputItems.length;i++) {
        inputItems[i].checked = false;
}
```

EDIT:::

Added this code specific to check box.

```
function resetRadioButtonValuesforCheckbox(checkbox) {
        var inputItems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if(! checkbox.checked){
        for (var i=0;i<inputItems.length;i++) {
                inputItems[i].checked = false;
        }
        }
```

Comment: thank you. actually i have check box and two radio button in one TD. when i uncheck the check box i have to clear the radio selction. Like this i have another four different td's have the similar structure. wanted to have a single method for all.

Answer (score 0):

this code uncheck all radio buttons

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false);
```

this code is of jquery so to run this code you need to include jquery library.

Comment: thank u sohil for your reply. I was looking for java script solution rather than jquery.